# Passing parameters to HIVE query

Tags: hive, hiveql

I am passing parameter to HIVE script like this using --hiveconf parameter to pass one value to HIVE query. Is there any other way to pass parameters to HIVE script?

```
beeline -u "${dbconection}" --hiveconf load_id=${loadid} -f /etc/sql/hive_script.sql
```

hive_script.sql is doing selecting records from table-a and inserting in table-b.

```
INSERT into TABLE table-b
SELECT column1,
Column2,
Column3,
${hiveconf:loadid} as load_id,
Column5
From table-a;
```

I am getting following error message

```
Error: Failed to open new session: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify load_id at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime
```

Here is what setup for hive variable substitute in my environment.

```
 set hive.variable.substitute;
+--------------------------------+--+
|              set               |
+--------------------------------+--+
| hive.variable.substitute=true  |
+--------------------------------+--+
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using beeline , you need to use `--hivevar`

```
beeline -u "${dbconection}" --hivevar load_id=${loadid} -f /etc/sql/hive_script.sql
```

.sql or .hql extension will not make a difference.

And hive query will use variable in following way :

```
INSERT into TABLE table-b
SELECT column1,
Column2,
Column3,
${loadid} as load_id,
Column5
From table-a;
```

Comment: Cool, if it worked for you, please feel free to upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I used and it work for me instead of "--hiveconf" use "--hivevar" this will work for HIVE version v0.8.X and above  .

```
loaded='201810251040'
beeline -u "${dbconection}" --hivevar load_id=${loadid} -f /etc/sql/hive_script.sql
```

Update hive_script.sql as follows

```
INSERT into TABLE table-b
SELECT column1,
Column2,
Column3,
${hivevar:load_id} as load_id,
Column5
From table-a;
```

This is pseudo code ....